# I have updated jQuery & jQuery UI to: jquery-1.9.0.min.js and jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, ui

> I have just updated jQuery & jQuery UI to: jquery-1.9.0.min.js and 
>   jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js
>
> And... all my unobtrusive Ajax calls (Ajax.ActionLink, Ajax.BeginForm)
>   stopped working properly - they open results in a new page instead of
>   updating the existing div.
>
> And I get this javascript error in Firebug when my page loads:

[image]

> The code hasn't changed of course, just updated the jQuery scripts
>   using Nuget.
>
> Anyone experienced the same problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `.live()` has been deprecated since 1.7 and was officially [removed in
>   jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Use `.on()` instead as it is the preferred method of
>   doing the [same thing](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
>
> Hope, It's Helpful for You